# Use regex to attach a '.' for each sequential Upper Case char

Tags: c++, regex

`I Foo bar DNA`

I want to replace `DNA` with `D.N.A` (`D.N.A.` also is ok), but not to replace 'I' and 'Foo'.

I have some clues, but they all failed.

```
string s = "I Foo bar DNA";
cout << std::regex_replace(s, std::regex("([A-Z]){2,}"), "$1.") << endl;
//output: I Foo bar A.
```

or

```
cout << std::regex_replace(s, std::regex("([A-Z])[A-Z]"), "$1.") << endl;
//output: I Foo bar D.A
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
([A-Z])(?=[A-Z])
```

Replace with `$1.`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YFPv38/1)

Here,

- `([A-Z])` - matches and captures into Group 1 any ASCII uppercase letter
- `(?=[A-Z])` - the lookahead makes sure there is an ASCII uppercase letter after the previous one, but keeps the matched char outside of the overall match value.

[C++ demo](https://ideone.com/cI8q2P):

```
std::string s("I Foo bar DNA");
std::regex reg("([A-Z])(?=[A-Z])");
std::cout << std::regex_replace(s, reg, "$1.") << std::endl;
// => I Foo bar D.N.A
```